# I use flags in categories area grid view with card view and i cant click on 2nd tile in single click i need to press it 2nd time then it select

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, gridview, android-cardview

I use flags in categories area grid view with card view and when i select 1 it select and when I click on 2nd it don't select at 1st time I need to press it 2nd time what to do?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VU5Ux.jpg)

2.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tCAb.jpg)

Comment: If you have a view like grid then why are you not using _RecyclerView_?

Comment: not use recycleview

Comment: The main reason behind this error is you are using one variable for all cardView i.e. `isClicked` which is true when your clicked 2nd time. Create isClicked variable for each cardView like isClicked1, isClicked2 etc.

Comment: thanks can try this